# Remove duplicates in a 2D array and add the corresponding values

Tags: java, duplicates

I know theres a lot about removing duplicates but I can't seem to get it right, I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong. So the code below contains a nested for loop where it traverses through a image (that is a made of a matrix of size 256x256) then it is passed to ImagePlus to calculate the radius, theta and value. The problem is that in radius there are duplicates and I want to for every duplicate to sum up the value like this:

```
......
r=1.44 mm/c (167), value=63   
r=1.43 mm/c (167), value=77   
r=1.43 mm/c (168), value=70   
r=1.42 mm/c (169), value=63   
r=1.42 mm/c (169), value=64   
r=1.41 mm/c (170), value=70   
r=1.41 mm/c (171), value=67   
r=1.40 mm/c (171), value=71 
...........
```

so It should be like:

```
r= 1.43, value=147 (70+77)

r= 1.42, value= 127 (63+64)

r= 1.41, value= 137 (70+67)
....
```

This is what I have been trying but I haven't had any luck! I have also tried using Sets but I need this to be in a specific order and it can't mess that up.

```
 final XYSeries data = new XYSeries("Third");
 double rMax = -1;
double [][] radiusArray = new double[256][256];
double [][] valueArray = new double[256][256];
 for(int i =0; i< 256; i++){
  for(int y =0; y< 256; y++){
     //image.getPixel(i, y);
       //This is taking the pixel position and calculating the r and value at that pixel
     String x = image.getLocationAsString(i, y);
    String n = image.getValueAsString(i, y);


    String delim = ", value=";
    String [] tokens = n.split(delim);
    double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);

    //if(image.getR() < 1.43){
    String [] t = x.split("r=");
    String[] b = t[1].split(" mm/c");
    //System.out.print("Meet b:    "+b[0]);
    double radius = Double.parseDouble(b[0]);

    String [] theta = x.split("theta= ");
    String [] token2 = theta[1].split(Character.toString(IJ.degreeSymbol));
    float thetaNum = Float.parseFloat(token2[0]);
    //System.out.print("  This is the theta value:    "+thetaNum+"    ");

    if(radius > rMax){
       rMax = radius;
    }

    radiusArray[i][y] = radius;
    valueArray[i][y] = num;     

    //if(thetaNum <= 180.00){
    System.out.print(x);
    System.out.print(n);
    System.out.print("   "+num);

    System.out.println();
    data.add(radius, num);

    //}
//}
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

So I was able to get rid of duplicates but now it seems to be skipping every second number and I don't know why?

```
    double summation;
         for(int i=1; i< 256; i++){
             for(int y=1; y< 256; y++){
                 if(radiusArray[i] != radiusArray[y]){
                     //System.out.print("its okay"+radiusArray[i][y]+"     ");
                     String n = image.getValueAsString(i, y);

                     //System.out.println(valueArray[i][y]);
                     String delim = ", value=";
                        String [] tokens = n.split(delim);
                        double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
   //                           System.out.print(radiusArray[i][y]);
  //                            System.out.println("    value=    "+num);
                 }
                 else{
                     String n = image.getValueAsString(i, y);
                     String m = image.getValueAsString(i-1, y-1);
                        String delim = ", value=";
                        String [] tokens = n.split(delim);
                        double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);

                        String mDelim = ", value=";
                        String [] mtokens = m.split(delim);
                        double mnum = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
                        summation = mnum+ num;

                        System.out.print(radiusArray[i][y]);
                        System.out.println("   value=   "+summation);
                 }

             }
         }
```

This is what I get now:

```
1.64   value=   186.0
1.62   value=   130.0
1.61   value=   120.0
1.59   value=   150.0
1.58   value=   134.0
1.56   value=   130.0
1.55   value=   136.0
1.54   value=   108.0
1.52   value=   144.0
1.51   value=   118.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to find dupe, note though do not remove while looping; that would cause an array out of bounds. Maybe make another `array` labeled *duplicate* to add the dupes too and remove them after you find them.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(array[i] == array[j]) {
           // "i" would be a duplicate...
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you wouldn't lose the order of your arrays. Just make sure you **find** the duplicates then remove them.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Okay I tried that but now its skipping every second number for r. You can see it in my updated question now. Well basically it misses the numbers that don't have a duplicate and if I put the if statements- print statements back then I see duplicates in the code again. I don't know how to get rid of this.