# Keeping track of previous numbers in a for loop is not working

Tags: java, loops, duplicates

I know theres another question like this online but I can't get my code to work. I don't know if my if statements is incorrect or if its something else. This is an extension of my earlier questions
[Remove duplicates in a 2D array and add the corresponding values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047401/remove-duplicates-in-a-2d-array-and-add-the-corresponding-values)

The question is still the same but except instead of using a 2D array I am using a for loop and I wan't to keep track of the previous numbers in the for loop but when I print the numbers on to the console I get duplicate r values. I hope someone can help me see the mistake. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I am working on:

```
    double rMax = -1;
        double previous;
         for(int i =1; i< 256; i++){
                for(int y =1; y< 256; y++){
                    //image.getPixel(i, y);
                    String x = image.getLocationAsString(i, y);
                    String n = image.getValueAsString(i, y);


                    String delim = ", value=";
                    String [] tokens = n.split(delim);
                    double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);

                    //if(image.getR() < 1.43){
                        String [] t = x.split("r=");
                        String[] b = t[1].split(" mm/c");
                        //System.out.print("Meet b:    "+b[0]);
                        double radius = Double.parseDouble(b[0]);

                        String [] theta = x.split("theta= ");
                        String [] token2 = theta[1].split(Character.toString(IJ.degreeSymbol));
                        float thetaNum = Float.parseFloat(token2[0]);
                        //System.out.print("  This is the theta value:    "+thetaNum+"    ");

                        if(radius == rMax){
                            rMax = radius;
                        }

                        String prevX = image.getLocationAsString(i-1, y-1);
                        String prevN = image.getValueAsString(i-1, y-1);

                        String [] prevT = prevX.split("r=");
                        String[] prevB = prevT[1].split(" mm/c");
                        //System.out.print("Meet b:    "+b[0]);
                        double prev_radius = Double.parseDouble(prevB[0]);
                        previous = prev_radius;

                        if(previous == radius){
                            System.out.println(radius);
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println(radius);
                        }

                        //if(thetaNum <= 180.00){
                        data.add(radius, num);

                        //}
                    //}
                }
            }
         System.out.println(rMax);
```

This is what it prints:

```
1.59
1.59
1.58
1.58
1.57
1.56
1.56
1.55
1.55
1.54
1.54
1.53
1.52
1.52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the value of `previous` anywhere.

**Update**

Your code has so many problems.  It'll never update rMax, for example.  I think this code will do what you're trying to achieve, assuming that `data` is a dictionary of some kind.  If not you'll need to modify the code that updates the value stored for the radius.

```
double rMax = -1;
double previous = -1;
for(int i =1; i< 256; i++){
    for(int y =1; y< 256; y++){
        String x = image.getLocationAsString(i, y);
        String n = image.getValueAsString(i, y);

        String delim = ", value=";
        String [] tokens = n.split(delim);
        double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);

        String [] t = x.split("r=");
        String [] b = t[1].split(" mm/c");
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(b[0]);

        String [] theta = x.split("theta= ");
        String [] token2 = theta[1].split(Character.toString(IJ.degreeSymbol));
        float thetaNum = Float.parseFloat(token2[0]);

        if(radius > rMax){
            rMax = radius;
        }

        if(radius == previous){
            data[radius] += num;
        }
        else {
            data.Add(radius, num);
        }
     }
}
System.out.println(rMax);
```

And, by the way, this code would be **so** much easier to read if you used Regex to capture the values from the string rather than all the confusing splits.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that in the question when I was copying and pasting but it doesn't seem to still fix it. I don't know if its the if statement that is incorrect. Cause I only want the duplicate r value to be printed once not twice. So I don't know whats wrong with the code.

Comment: I have added the recently updated code in my question. But I can't seem to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Okay, so now your code does exactly the same thing regardless of whether or not `radius == previous`.  The `if` and `else` blocks are identical, and the values get added to the `data` collection regardless.